# Yii2 Custom Class - namespace error

Tags: namespaces, yii2

I am trying to create a custom class that can be called to convert dates and times for MySQL.

I am using the Yii2 Basic template

I have created a folder and a file in components called Convert.php

```
<?
namespace app\components;

use Yii;

class Convert
{
    const DATE_FORMAT = 'php:Y-m-d';
    const DATETIME_FORMAT = 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s';
    const TIME_FORMAT = 'php:H:i:s';

    public static function toMysql($dateStr, $type='date', $format = null) {
        if ($type === 'datetime') {
              $fmt = ($format == null) ? self::DATETIME_FORMAT : $format;
        }
        elseif ($type === 'time') {
              $fmt = ($format == null) ? self::TIME_FORMAT : $format;
        }
        else {
              $fmt = ($format == null) ? self::DATE_FORMAT : $format;
        }
        return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($dateStr, $fmt);
    }   
}

?>
```

I then try and call this method in my controller

```
use app\components\Convert;

...

public function actionCreate()
{
    ...
    $model->date_of_birth = Convert::toMysql($model->date_of_birth);
    ...
}
```

However I am getting the following error

Unable to find 'app\components\Convert' in file: /var/www/html/portal/components/Convert.php. Namespace missing?

I am probably missing something simple, but I cannot see it.

Thanks for your help.

Liam

From the comments, I have found that the error was a simple mistake, the opening tag should have been

```
<?php
```

Comment: In Yii configuration file you have to say to Yii to import folder from your Components folder, otherwise your class is not visible.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong MrD, you don't need to import class in Yii2, it will be autoloaded

Comment: It is may be just a short open tag problem, you should always use `<?php`

Comment: soju, i think you may be right here.. will let you know, i have more errors lol

Comment: OK, thanks soju, the issue from the above code is the opening tag, what an idiot i am. soju, do you want to add an answer and i will tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error simply means php cannot find the namespace in this file, and since the namespace seems to be correct, it is probably a php opening tag error.

Depending on your server php configuration, [short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) could be disabled, you should always use `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend base Component from Yii2:

```
<?php
namespace app\components;
use yii\base\Component;

use Yii;

class Convert extends Component
{
    const DATE_FORMAT = 'php:Y-m-d';
```

And then put in config/web.php

```
'components' => [
    'convert' => [
       'class' => 'app\components\Convert',
     ],
]
```

and access it as

```
$model->date_of_birth = Yii::$app->convert->toMysql($model->date_of_birth);
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the answer, I saw this, I just thought i could include by the use; at the top, i am still learning about namespaces - What about then including the file in the index.php as a require, or is this going against the way Yii2 works? sorry for sounding dumb lol

Comment: OK, I followed the instructions and i have this error now - Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::Convert

Comment: Try Yii::$app->convert , with lowercase

Comment: If I use Yii::$app->convert->toMysql($model->date_of_birth) (lower case) and I get this error - Unable to find 'app\components\Convert' in file: /var/www/html/portal/components/Convert.php. Namespace missing?

Comment: @soju what do you mean?

Comment: @Liam was the php tag the only problem ?

Comment: Yes for me to be able to use my original solution. Not sure about the second one, I assume the Capital C needed to be lower case.

Comment: @Liam it needs to be lower because in config file is defined as `convert`